# Why is this WCF service not recognizing the UriTemplate parameter?

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

I've created the following RESTful WCF service, which works just fine when running it in VS.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    UriTemplate = "/sales/start={start}&end={end}")]
List<Sales> GetSalesByDate(string start, string end);
```

However, when deploying this to my test server (running Win2K3 and IIS6) I received the following server error:

*Operation 'GetSalesByDate' in contract 'ISalesService' uses GET, but also has body parameter 'start'. GET operations cannot have a body. Either make the parameter 'start' a UriTemplate parameter, or switch from WebGetAttribute to WebInvokeAttribute.*

Obviously I have already made 'start' a UriParameter. So can anyone tell me why an exception is being thrown?

EDIT:
For reference, here is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="Services.SalesService">
                <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" 
                          binding="webHttpBinding" 
                          contract="Services.ISalesService"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="webBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out `/sales/start={start}&end={end}` is not a valid Uri (duh!). After a little trial and error I finally figured this out. Tweaking the UriTemplate with a '?' solved the problem.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    UriTemplate = "/sales/?start={start}&end={end}")]
List<Sales> GetSalesByDate(string start, string end);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand why it worked on the dev box, but not on the server.  But I'm glad you are unblocked!

Answer (score 4):

I know it is really late but why didn't you use the following format.

```
UriTemplate = "/sales/{start}/{end}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is that the dev machine has SP1 and the server does not.

http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2008/08/22/rest-in-wcf-part-ix-controlling-the-uri.aspx

Comment: No, SP1 is installed. That was the first thing I checked.